# Can I use the default pdf reader in desktop ui mode

Tags: windows-8, pdf-reader

The default pdf handler in Windows 8 is the "Reader" app, which runs in the new UI only. Aside from using a "normal" pdf reader (Foxit/Adobe) is there any other way I can make the Reader app run in desktop ui mode.
[image]

I am looking for this, because I am used to opening PDF and an editor side by side (50%). The modern UI only gives me one-thirds, which is not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible because the Reader app was only made to be run Windows 8. (Basically what I mean is that you can only run the Reader app from the Start page)

Answer (score 4):

You can "snap" the Windows Reader to the Desktop.

1. Open Windows Reader
2. Go to Desktop
3. Point with the mouse to the top-left corner until a box with Windows Reader icon appears
4. Right click on it, and select Snap left or Snap Right

Answer (score 1):

No.

The  PDF reader is a Modern UI app; you cannot run Modern UI apps on the desktop.

You could run it on a virtual machine instead.

Comment: wait. Run a whole OS *just* to read PDFs?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Control Panel - Default programs and change the file association for .pdf to acrobat reader or foxit or whatever reader you prefer.

PDF's will then open up in windowed mode.

Answer (score 0):

Not UI mode but it is more manageable with :

Windows key and left, right arrow will make it 50% of the screen.
Process to use the windows key and D to put the desktop on the other side.

You also have got a bar you can move to set the size for yourself then